# Kingston DataTraveler DTSE9H recognized but assigned no drive letter

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive

I just bought a [32GB Kingston DataTraveler DTSE9H thumbdrive](http://www.kingston.com/en/usb/personal_business#dtse9h). Using the default Windows7 driver, the keydrive is correctly detected, but for some reason is assigned no drive letter:

[image]

[Kingston's solution](http://www.kingston.com/en/support/technical/products?model=DTII) is to "Unplug [other USB devices], insert the DataTraveler drive and restart the system. After the DataTraveler is configured you should then be able to connect [other USB devices.]", but this doesn't work with either of my two Windows7 hosts (desktop and laptop).

Any idea what it is and what I could try?

Could it be because of that EFI thingie?

Thank you.

---

Edit: After using Disk Management to delete the Primary Partition on the drive, I'm left with the 200MB EFI System Partition and the 28.70GB "Unallocated" space. What should I do next to get a single partition, format it, and have Windows7 assign a drive letter to it?
[image]

---

Edit: When right-clicking on the Unallocated Partition, I'm not given the opportunity to format the drive:
[image]

Comment: Right click on desired partition (in your case, the second 28.57gb one), change drive letter, add a drive letter

Comment: Thanks but no go: It just says "Properties"

Comment: Problem solved, using the faithful Rufus application.

https://rufus.akeo.ie/

Comment: Then post that as an answer, not a comment. As well, please try not to edit when it starts asking new questions; it makes it more difficult to understand what's happening

Comment: The reason I did it, is that it's not possible to post screenshots in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't support multiple partitions on flash drives correctly. Here's a screenshot of a partitioned flash drive shown in *Disk Management* window:

[image: Screenshot from Disk Management]

Note that both partitions appear to have no drive letters assigned. Actually the first partition has a letter which is nowhere to be found in *Disk Management* <sup>(1)</sup>:

[image: Screenshot from Windows Explorer]

In your case the first partition is an EFI System Partition. Partitions of this kind are always hidden, so no partitions are available.

---

To make this drive usable again you have to repartition it. Depending on partition formats this may or may not be possible with *Disk Management*, but `diskpart` tool (included with Windows) will always do the trick:

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> and type `diskpart`. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to run it as administrator. UAC prompt will appear, confirm by clicking OK.
2. Type `list disk` in the *diskpart* console:

   [image: Diskpart disk list screenshot]

   Find your drive in this list. Mine is *Disk 2*
3. Select your disk by typing `select disk X`: (substitute X for appropriate number)

   [image: Diskpart disk selection screenshot]
4. Type `list partition`. A list of partitions will appear. **Make sure you have selected correct drive. Deleting partitions will destroy data on them.**

   [image: Diskpart partition list screenshot]
5. Use `select partition X` and `delete partition` commands to delete all partitions on this disk. Note that partition numbers may change between deletions, so use `list partition` each time.

   [image: Diskpart partition deletion screenshot]
6. At this point you should end up with no partitions:

   [image: Diskpart showing no partitions]
7. Fire up *Disk Management* (<kbd>Win</kbd> `diskmgmt.msc` <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and create a new volume by right-clicking on empty space.

   [image: Disk Management screenshot]

---

<sup>(1)</sup> This depends on partition formats. These screenshots were taken for exFAT partitions (which are supported by Windows). With FAT32 partition a letter would be assigned in *Disk Management*.